# How to retrieve the configured base URL from the Spring WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-webclient

The Spring reactive [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) can be built with a base URL:

```java
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
...
@Bean
public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
    return builder
            .baseUrl("http://example.org")
            .build();
    // or alternatively a shortcut
    // return WebClient.create("http://example.org");
}
```

Is there a way to **retrieve** the configured base URL back from an **already existing** `WebClient` instance?

Something like:

```java
@Autowired
private WebClient webClient;
...
String baseUrl = webClient.getBaseUrl(); // I want to know how this WebClient is configured
assertEquals("http://example.org", baseUrl);
```

Or something like

```java
var configuration = webClient.getConfiguration(); 
String baseUrl = configuration.getBaseUrl();
assertEquals("http://example.org", baseUrl);
```

I understand that the handling of the parameter is internal and implementation specific. However I don't understand why, if it is the *interface* who exposes the setter (via the builder or the factory method argument), it also does *not* expose a getter. I am not specifying the implementation when creating the instance. So I would naturally expect the interface to tell me with what value it was created. I cannot see any plausible reason why this information is not exposed in the interface itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebClient is an interface with no API to get back the base URL, so maybe some implementation class has one but that will make your code dependent on the chosen one.

Comment: The reason why I don't like it that it's the **interface** which has the setter (via the builder or the factory method argument) for the `baseUrl`. I am *not specifying the implementation* when creating the instance. So I would naturally expect the interface to tell me with what value it was created. I cannot see any plausible reason why this information is not exposed *in the interface itself*.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get this information from the implementing class, in my case DefaultWebClient is injected. So calling the code below returns the base url.

```
((DefaultWebClient) webClient).builder.baseUrl
```

Comment: Your answer, however true, goes against the philosophy of my question. As I did not specify the implementation class of the `WebClient` interface, my code must not be dependent on any assumptions about which class implements it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not a philosopher. You should raise a change request/bug report against Spring library then.